# webpage is not auto fit in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had designed a login pop up on my website.

It is properly aligned and displayed in laptop browser but in mobile, it is being displayed very small.I need help in adding some bootstrap tags by which it would be compatible with mobile browser too.

Below is the demonstration of the code snippet you can see working

```js
function PopUp(hideOrshow) {
    if (hideOrshow == 'hide') document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = "none";
    else document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').removeAttribute('style');
}
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        PopUp('show');
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
#ac-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 90px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*background: rgba(34,34,34,0.75);*/
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
       /*rgba(255, 255, 255, .6)*/
    z-index: 1001;
}




@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);    
/****** LOGIN MODAL ******/
.loginmodal-container {
  max-width: 350px;
  width: 100% !important;
  background-color: #eceff6;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: roboto;
  border:2px solid;
  border-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#popupHeader
{
    background-color:#3c5899;padding:12px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}
.loginmodal-container form{padding:35px;}
.loginmodal-container h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin:0px;
  font-family: roboto;
  color:#fff;
}

.loginmodal-container input[type=button] {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.loginmodal-container input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 08px 16px;
    margin: 2px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 06px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.loginmodal-container input[type=text]:hover, input[type=password]:hover {
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  border-top: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.loginmodal {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 0 8px;
/* border-radius: 3px; */
/* -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; */
}

.loginmodal-submit {
  /* border: 1px solid #3079ed; */
  border: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
  background-color: #5e75a7;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  font-family: roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top:2px;
  border-radius:4px;
}

.loginmodal-submit:hover {
  /* border: 1px solid #2f5bb7; */
  border: 0px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background-color: #6a8acf;
}

.loginmodal-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: opacity ease 0.5s;
} 

.login-help{
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom:50px;
}
.login-help a{display:block;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="JavaScript.js"></script>

<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mtbc.formstack.com/forms/js.php/90_day_review_form_copy"></script><noscript><a href="https://mtbc.formstack.com/forms/90_day_review_form_copy" title="Online Form">Employee Self Evaluation form</a></noscript>

<div id="ac-wrapper">

    <div id="popup">
        <center>            
            
             <div class="modal fade"  id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="loginmodal-container">
                    <div class="row" id="popupHeader">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 text">
                           <img src="logo.png" width="80" height="30" align="center">
   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div align="center">
                      <img src="https://scontent.fisb1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.2080-6/c0.0.76.76/p75x75/851562_581386735219055_1520422143_n.png?oh=ac209d564ee1a2c80984e673d168272b&amp;oe=5A134903" width="50" class="_3-q3 img">
                      <br/><br/>
                         <div style="opacity: 0.5;">Log in to your Facebook account <br> to access formstack</div>
                         
                    </div>
                   
      <form>
     <input type="text" name="user" id="UEmail" placeholder="Email address or phone number" required>
                
     <input type="password"  id="UPass" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required>
                   

    <input type="button" name="login" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Login">
                     
      <font size="1.5px"><h1 align="center">  <a href="https://www.facebook.com">Create account</a></h1></font>
      <br>
                  
                  <font size="1.5px"><h1>  <a href="https://www.facebook.com">Forgetten password?</a></h1></font>
    </div>

          
</form>
   
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing critical meta viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

See [CSS Tricks: Responsive meta tag](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)

Comment: Not clear what specific problem is. That page seems responsive to me

Comment: This is current view on my mobile.Pop up seems too big here now. https://ibb.co/h9Z2JG

Comment: No idea what your expectations are

Comment: I am simply asking that now it is perfect but too much zoomed. How can i zoom out

Comment: Suggest you do some reading up on using css media queries in responsive pages